# Matrix Covariance Algebra

Tags: variance, covariance, structural-equation-modeling, covariance-matrix

In the structural equation modeling (SEM) context, one of the modeling frameworks is called the reticular action model (RAM). In RAM, the observed variables (y) and latent variables (η) are combined in one vector.

```
v = [y η](transpose of this matrix)
```

This can be modeled with an asymmetric matrix **A** and a symmetric matrix **S**:

```
v = Av + u
u ∼ N(0,S)
```

I want to derive the **var(v)** in terms of **A** and **S**. Using matrix covariance algebra, I tried to do this:

```
var(Av + u)
cov(Av + u, Av + u)
cov(Av,Av + u) + cov(u,Av + u)
cov(Av,Av) + cov(Av,u) + cov(u,Av) + cov(u,u)
```

The last term is the variance of u, therefore equivalent to **S**, but I am unsure about the rest.

Answer (score 0):

#### Hint

For random vectors $u, v$ and fixed conformative matrices $A, B$, one has
$$ \operatorname{Cov}(Au, Bv) = A\operatorname{Cov}(u, v)B^\top.$$
The proof is a straightforward check of the definition of the covariance operator in multivariate analysis.

Now find proper $A, B$ for each term in your expansion (but one thing you need to confirm is: is the correlation structure between $u$ and $v$ known? Or do you assume they are just uncorrelated?).